# ¿Como pintar inputs y texto de acuerdo a unidades de un producto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estoy haciendo una aplicación tipo inventario que de acuerdo a una factura de compra pueda consultar los productos relacionados a esa factura y pueda agregarle un input y un botón para enviar cierta información a la BD de cada producto de la factura. Si, por ejemplo, en la factura hay 5 botes de Leche de sabor, como puedo hacer para que aparezcan 5 filas con el texto Leche de sabor ya que cada producto es individual.

Lo que he logrado hacer es que haciendo una tabla html sume la cantidad total de productos, y de acuerdo a ese resultado, dibujo una tabla html con esa cantidad de filas. Lo que no sé es como mostrar los textos.

[image: ejemplo]

mi codigo para generar la tabla es

```js
var suma = 0;
  $('#grillaArt tr').each(function() {
    suma += parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(1).text() || 0, 10)
  })

  jQuery = $;
  jQuery("#generaTabla").hide().fadeIn("Slow");

  var NroFila = suma;
  var Cantidad = NroFila * NroFila + 1;
  var valor = Cantidad * 1300;


  jQuery('#tblTabla tr').next().remove();
  var a = 0;

  for (var x = 0; x < NroFila; x++) {
    Cantidad = Cantidad + x;
    valor = valor * Cantidad;
    a = a + 1;
    jQuery('#tblTabla tr:last').after('<tr>' +
      '<td align="left">' + a + '</td>' +
      '<td align="left">' + Cantidad + '</td>' +
      '<td align="left">' + valor + '</td>' +
      '<td align="center"><button>Agregar</button></td></tr>'
    );
  }

  jQuery('#tblTabla tr:odd').css('background-color', '#E9F0F8');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="generaTabla" style="display: none">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" id="tblTabla" style="color: #333333; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr style="color: White; background-color: #5D7B9D; font-weight: bold;">
      <th align="left">Nro</th>
      <th align="left">Cantidad</th>
      <th align="left">Valor</th>
      <th style="text-align:center">Agregar</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alfonso Carrasco amigo tu sabes como?

Comment: no se entiende bien.. ¿puedes explicar a nivel de la interface eliminado lo especifico de la aplicacion?

Comment: @md del ejemplo de la imagen hay 12 unidades de leche blanca y 12 unidades de leche de sabor, en total son 24 unidades, estas unidades las quiero convertir a filas (24) en las que quiero que aparezca el texto leche de sabor 12 veces(o sea filas) y el texto leche blanca 12 veces(o sea filas)

Comment: @md ya tengo el código para que el total de unidades sean filas en una tabla HTML, asi como también ya se como agregar el botón a cada fila, el problema es que no se como hacer para colocar en cada fila el texto leche de sabor y leche blanca según el numero de unidades que tenga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ivxn; Aquí te dejo un código que tambien podría resolver a tu situación, esta opción esta desarrollado sin Jquery, es nativa.

Puedes adaptarlo a tus necesidades. Éxito en tu código.

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll("#origen tbody tr"); // Buscamos la tabla que contiene los datos como origen
if(a!= undefined || a != null){
  var cc = 1; //Este será un contador que controlara los registros de la tabla destino
  var fila = ""; //Iniciamos una variable que indudablemente será una fila; TR
  for(var b in a){ //Iteramos los datos que nos entrego el querySelectorAll.
    var c = a[b];
    
    if(typeof c == "object"){ //Solo nos important los objetos
      var limite = c.children[1].textContent; //Accesamos al número 12 que es la cantidad.
      for(var x=0;x<limite;x++){//Hacemos un ciclo de la cantidad
        //A continuación vamos a crear nuestra fila con la variable; fila
        fila += "<tr><td>"+(cc)+"</td><td>"+(x+1)+"</td><td>"+c.children[2].textContent+"</td><td><button>Agregar</button></td></tr>";
        cc++;
      }
    }
  }
  var t = document.querySelector("#destino tbody"); //Ahora buscamos la tabla destino
  if(t != undefined || t != null){
    t.innerHTML = fila; //Le agregamos los datos de la fila.
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="origen">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Factura</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Articulo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>004</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Lecha Blanca</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>004</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Leche Sabor</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr/>
<table id="destino">
  <thead><tr><th>No</th><th>Cantidad</th><th>Valor</th><th>Agregar</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucione el problema, recorro mi tabla fila x fila ($('#grillaArt tr').each), de la columna cantidad de mi tabla HTML, obtengo y guardo el valor numérico y el texto del producto que se encuentran en el td 1 y 2, en las variables sum y valor_ga, después genero una tabla html con Jquery y agrego un ciclo for para ir dibujando las filas con sus respectivos textos y el codigo de abajo es el source code completo de la tabla que queria realizar =)

```
$('#grillaArt tr').each(function () { //filas con clase 'dato', especifica una clase, asi no tomas el nombre de las columnas
    sum = parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
    valorga = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text();

    jQuery = $;
    jQuery("#generaTabla1").hide().fadeIn("Slow");

    for (var j = 0; j < sum; j++) {
        contador = contador + 1;
        jQuery('#tblTabla1 tr:last').after('<tr>' +
        '<td align="left">' + contador + '</td>' +
        '<td align="left">' + valor_ga + '</td>' +
        '<td align="left"></td>' +
        '<td align="center"><button>Agregar</button></td></tr>'
        );
    }
});
```